# how can i use Mercurial to run unit tests for Python

Tags: python, mercurial, python-unittest

and also do code coverage analysis. I am using ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [link](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WritingTests) to an example using Mercurial hooks that might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Mercurial hooks](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Hook) of course!  As far as what tools you want to do for the test running and the code coverage, that's up to you, but mercurial hooks are the way to arbitrarily run things when there's been a commit.